# Printing momentjs object within angular templates

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I am trying to print momentjs object not ISO8601 string within angularjs templates.

let's say I have something i.e

`$scope.time = moment();`

and in my template when I do the following

`<span ng-bind="time"></span>` or `<span>{{time}}</span>`

I guess what I am trying to do is to avoid calling momentjs `toString()` or `.toJSON()` object which might be triggers by `{{}}`, however, I do not want to override those function that are chained onto moments prototype.

Comment: What are you trying to display exactly? If you want to show a textual representation of `time` then use `format('')` on the moment object. See [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Comment: No I want to display an actual object, not the actual representation of time.

Comment: Can you show us how you're expecting that to look?

Comment: I got it `<span ng-bind="demo.$time.toObject()|json"></span>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<span ng-bind="demo.$time.toObject()|json"></span>`

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-object/